# How can I use this if i'm using two class together using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to select two classes but there is one issue if I want to use this just for single class how can I use that? Like given below:-

```js
$('.city-selector ul li, .city-selector-close').click(function() {
  var selectedCity = $(this).text();
  $('.selected-city span').text(selectedCity);
})
```

```css
.city-selector-close {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="city-selector-close">X</div>
<div class="city-selector">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">Gurgaon</li>
    <li>Delhi</li>
    <li>Noida</li>
    <li>Faridabad</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="selected-city"><span>Gurgaon</span></div>
```

in above example everything working fine like which city I want to select. I'm able to select but there is one issue when I select two class together `.city-selector ul li, .city-selector-close` and I just want to get text of clicked class

Still everything working fine, but when I click on close then it will be also working like selected city how to solve this issue with this approach?

Comment: I don't understand the problem - why would you ever want to update the text when you click the close icon? Just use two separate event handlers.

Comment: actually i can do this with two separate events handlers but i just want to know how fix this type of issue when i have to work with single handler?

Comment: It's hard to understand the issue though, as the example makes no sense.

Comment: @RohitVerma In that case you can simply use if condition and seperate the events. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56666569/4354201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would favour two separate click handlers too, but if you realllly want to use a single one, you could check the class of the clicked element using the `hasClass` function:

```
$('.city-selector ul li, .city-selector-close').click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('city-selector-close')) {
    var selectedCity = $(this).text();
    $('.selected-city span').text(selectedCity);
  }
});
```

But echoing what the other answerers have said, it makes much more sense to split this functionality out into two separate click handlers.

Comment: Thanks @Phil you answered like exactly i want!

I don't use separate handlers for this because if i use separate handlers then i have to use too much code two times

thats why i'm not able to do that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I agree with you, but he wanted to know how it could be done within one function and this is what I've offered. Indeed, he should split it into two handlers, this is just an alternative (albeit a worse one).

Comment: True. That wasn't a constructive comment - I apologise.

Comment: @RohitVerma: *"then i have to use too much code two times"* - The "don't repeat yourself" mantra is referring to logic, not to keystrokes.  If your primary goal in programming is to produce as few keystrokes as possible then you're going to write *very* difficult to support code.  This current example is relatively minor, but in a full featured application this endeavor will cost you many, *many* hours of frustrating work all just to save a few bytes of storage space.

Answer (score 2):

It *sounds like* what you're trying to describe are two separate click handlers.  One for clicking the cities, one for clicking the X:

```js
$('.city-selector ul li').click(function() {
  var selectedCity = $(this).text();
  $('.selected-city span').text(selectedCity);
})

$('.city-selector-close').click(function() {
  $('.selected-city span').text('');
})
```

```css
.city-selector-close {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="city-selector-close">X</div>
<div class="city-selector">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">Gurgaon</li>
    <li>Delhi</li>
    <li>Noida</li>
    <li>Faridabad</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="selected-city"><span>Gurgaon</span></div>
```

It's not necessary, or even wise, to condense everything into a single click handler or a single function.  Your elements do two different things, so have two different functions for them.

Answer (score 2):

If You want to handle this you can create 2 different event handlers

```js
$('.city-selector ul li').click(function() {
  var selectedCity = $(this).text();
  $('.selected-city span').text(selectedCity);
})
$('.city-selector-close').click(function() {
  alert("close");
})
```

```css
.city-selector-close {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="city-selector-close">X</div>
<div class="city-selector">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">Gurgaon</li>
    <li>Delhi</li>
    <li>Noida</li>
    <li>Faridabad</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="selected-city"><span>Gurgaon</span></div>
```

Or if you want to use the same way as your code you can use the `If` condition and seperate it.

```js
$('.city-selector ul li , .city-selector-close').click(function() {
  var selectedCity = $(this).text();
  if(selectedCity == "X"){
    alert("close");
  }else{
    $('.selected-city span').text(selectedCity);
  }
})
```

```css
.city-selector-close {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="city-selector-close">X</div>
<div class="city-selector">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">Gurgaon</li>
    <li>Delhi</li>
    <li>Noida</li>
    <li>Faridabad</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="selected-city"><span>Gurgaon</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the classname of the element that caused the click event using

```
$(this).attr('class')
```

So inside the callback function check if it's **city-selector-close** and in case it is not display the text.

```js
$('.city-selector ul li, .city-selector-close').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('class') != "city-selector-close") {
    var selectedCity = $(this).text();
    $('.selected-city span').text(selectedCity);
  }
})
```

```css
.city-selector-close {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="city-selector-close">X</div>
<div class="city-selector">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">Gurgaon</li>
    <li>Delhi</li>
    <li>Noida</li>
    <li>Faridabad</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="selected-city"><span>Gurgaon</span></div>
```